# Can I recover a Bitlocker-encrypted disk without the key?

Tags: encryption

I have encrypted an external drive using Bitlocker on windows 7, I have lost the recovery key and since upgraded my PC with a new motherboard and processor. i have tried everything imaginable to recover my data, I have used passware etc and other forensic software packages but no joy. I have turned to Ubuntu to hopefully resolve my issue.

Where I am at the moment is that I have installed the external hard drive directly on to my machine and have loaded Ubuntu rev 14.04. Ubuntu recognises the drive in the disk management section but will not mount it.

Are there any packages I can use to decrypt my drive? Any help (in basic instructions please !! pardon my ignorance) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to [get a recovery key from Microsoft](https://onedrive.live.com/recoverykey) and then do the recovery in Windows.

If you didn't set up a recovery key, your future is a lot more bleak. Here's the snip from the [MS Bitlocker recovery FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/bitlocker-recovery-keys-faq):

> Unfortunately, if you can’t find your key, and no other administrator on the PC can find a backup copy either, you’ll need to restore the PC to factory default settings. Only choose this option as a last resort because it will delete your personal data from the PC. While it helps protect your data against unauthorized access, it also prevents you from ever accessing your data again.

Bitlocker is *proper* strong encryption.
You aren't going to crack it without a key in your lifetime.

Nothing in Ubuntu will change that.